# Create a Bluetooth Chat

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat

I have checked good enough tutorials to make a Bluetooth chat,there is some way I am not being able to complete it,I would appreciate Any clear/recommended tutorial or the source code,I can post the code,but It is messed up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code in GitHub
[Android BluetoothChat Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)